# Samsung galaxy S3 phonenumber sync facebook

Tags: sync, facebook, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I had the HTC wildfire S like a week ago. It managed to automaticly fill my contact list with phone numbers and pictures from Facebook. Is this function not in the galaxy s3?
If so, how can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [Haxsync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mots.haxsync) to sync Facebook data to your phone, works great for me.

Comment: Does this work for phone numbers, though? This is my current issue.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to sync phone numbers for some reason. Good point, didn't notice that before!

Comment: I'm sure it used to, I recommended it for this exact purpose yesterday, but after research found it doesn't any more. Apparently Facebook have blocked all third party apps from this function. Grr!

Answer (score 0):

Go to **contacts**....Press the left button (the settings button) and then **Accounts**. Here you can add your facebook account. (Also I guess if you use facebook app, it asks you whether you want to sync contacts or not.)